# CSS hover disappears at mouseover

Tags: css, image, hover

I am just trying to do a map which has different places/points on it. If you pull the arrow/mouse over one of the points, the transparent image positioned on that point should change into an image with a name on it. So it would be an image-changing hover. BUT - its totally going wrong. The image with the name is there all the time and when I pull the mouse over it, the transparent one appears. I tried changing the pictures but it didn't work.

the CSS:

```
.nutbrown img { 
position:absolute;
margin:497px 642px 247px 380px;
background:url("test1.png") no-repeat;
height: 20px;
text-decoration: none;
}

.nutbrown:hover img {
position:absolute;
height: 20px;
visibility:hidden;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

The HTML

```
<div class="nutbrown"> <img src="test.png" /></div>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Because of this `visibility:hidden;`

You are telling to CSS to hide every image inside .nutbrown when you hover .nutbrown